# Dynamic landing page - am I doing this right?

Tags: plugins

What I want:

When a user goes to:

> www.mydomain.com/details/?pid=12345

he is taken to a landing page that loads up a user-specified template, fills it with the details from our DB, and then prints it out.  I do NOT want a separate page/post for each product; I want it created dynamically from the DB each time.  (Yes, I understand the ramifications.)

What I've done:

- Created a plugin "PD" that lets a user specify the template (eg: `"{title}<br>{description}"`) and it saves the option as 'pd_template'.
- Created a new 'details.php' called "Details" in the Theme that displays some theme-specific headers, etc, and calls my pd_display(`$_GET['pid']`) to show the main content.
- Created a new Page in WP with the slug "details" and set it's page template to "Details"

This seems like a very convoluted way to do all this.  Can someone explain a better, cleaner way of doing this?

[Bonus Points]  If you can show me how to use a URL like

> www.mydomain.com/details/12345

instead of ?pid=12345  that would be just peachy.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to hook wp and check for a 404 that contains your dynamic pagename:

```
function wpse27761_dynamic_page() {
    global $wp, $wp_query;
    if($wp_query->is_404 ):
        if( strpos($wp->request, 'mypagename') !== false ):
            $wp_query->is_404 = false;
            //create a post object with your desired output
        endif;
    endif;
}
add_action('wp', 'wpse27761_dynamic_page');
```

but it's arguably more complex, I would personally just do it the way you're doing it now, though I usually just create a page-details.php template so you don't have to explicitly set a template for the page.

as for the rewrite, with your current scheme it's pretty simple:

```
function wpse27657_rewrite(){
    add_rewrite_rule('details/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?pagename=details&pid=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpse27657_rewrite' );  

function wpse27657_query_var( $query_vars ){
    $query_vars[] = 'pid';
    return $query_vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpse27657_query_var' );
```

this will route `/details/whatever/` to your pagename details with the pid query var set. just be sure to visit your permalink settings page and save so these new rules are added. `get_query_var('pid')` will return your query var in the template.

Comment: Well, I'll leave the setup as I have it then.  It works, and that's all that matters.  Thanks for the rewrite rule help; it works great and looks MUCH nicer now.  :)